# cassandra.bat throws java.io.IOException: rename failed of LocationInfo-e -1-Data.db in 0.7rc1

Tags: java, batch-file, cassandra, windows-xp-sp3

I've followed the Getting Started instructions for single node and it worked fine in cassandra-0.7beta2. But when trying to do the same for cassandra-0.7rc1 it spews out the following stack trace:

```
 INFO 20:21:37,771 Starting up server gossip
 INFO 20:21:37,786 switching in a fresh Memtable for LocationInfo at CommitLogContext(file='/var/lib
/cassandra/commitlog\CommitLog-1290885697489.log', position=700)
 INFO 20:21:37,786 Enqueuing flush of Memtable-LocationInfo@29247351(227 bytes, 4 operations)
 INFO 20:21:37,786 Writing Memtable-LocationInfo@29247351(227 bytes, 4 operations)
ERROR 20:21:38,161 Fatal exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:1,5,main]
java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException: rename failed of D:\var\lib\cassandra\data\system\LocationInfo-e-1-Data.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.rename(SSTableWriter.java:214)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:184)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.closeAndOpenReader(SSTableWriter.java:167)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:161)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.access$000(Memtable.java:49)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$1.runMayThrow(Memtable.java:174)
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: rename failed of D:\var\lib\cassandra\data\system\LocationInfo-e-1-Data.db
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.renameWithConfirm(FBUtilities.java:359)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.rename(SSTableWriter.java:210)
        ... 12 more
```

Someone posted this problem on cassandra's [mailing list](http://www.mail-archive.com/user@cassandra.apache.org/msg07153.html).
It seems there's a problem, when trying to rename the tmp files (e.g. LocationInfo-tmp-e-1-Data.db).
It happens in FBUtilities.java:

```
public static void renameWithConfirm(String tmpFilename, String filename) throws IOException
    {
        if (!new File(tmpFilename).renameTo(new File(filename)))
        {
            throw new IOException("rename failed of " + filename);
        }
    }
```

I should note that File.renameTo() is known to work funny on Windows.

Anyway... Help?

Answer (score 1):

Please create a bug report here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA